# How to overlap images using flexbox while maintaing it's ability responsive design

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, flexbox

[click here to see my code](https://codepen.io/van107/pen/wvvLapv)

The goal here is to perfectly overlap the images.
The eyes (blue ovals) should display on the face (peach circle). I'm using chrome as my browser. But hope it will display the same on any browser used.

Like so (minus the nose):

[image: Blue Ovals on top of peach cicle]

What I tried:

- changing the position of the images from relative to absolute (With one image set as absolute I should have been able to move it anywhere I wanted on the page.)
- setting align-self: flex-start (Sometimes browsers have weird default setting. I was told this might override a chrome default that was stopping me from moving the image.)
- setting align-self: center (This was also an attempt to override a chrome default)

I can't figure out how to overlap the two images let alone add any code to my CSS file that will move the images.

```js
function setDefaultImage(){
    var defaultImage = document.getElementById(img_face).src = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_seSuUcgJgd5qQTUcreDuYo_zfVpRzsa/view?usp=sharing";
   
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: darkred;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.flex-container > div {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 5%;
    width:38%;
}
img{
    align-self: flex-start;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.img_face{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.img_eyes{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <div class="flex-container">
    <div id = "left">
        <button  type="reset" id="reset" class="button" onclick = setDefaultImage()>Reset</button>
    </div>

    <div id = "right">
        <img id="img_face" src="white_face.png" alt="White Face" >
        <img id="img_eyes" src="blue_eyes.png" alt="Blue Eyes" >
   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I see a requirements list, care to share your attempt? It helps folks help you if they can help steer you past obstacles instead of just giving out answers. ;)

Comment: I don't really care if people just give me the answer. This isn't really an assignment for a class. It's just a project I came up with on my own. (Well techically it's extra credit for my biology class. But it's not a coding assignment.)

Comment: What @ChrisW. is trying to imply that you don't just need answers, you need answers that really helps you. If you properly state your attempt, it helps people to give good quality answers. ^_^

Comment: You can try to make your padding and margin negative.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple different approaches with room for tinkering to help your learning. Happy Holidays!

```js
hiUser = (val) => {
  const box1 = document.getElementById('box1'),
        box2 = document.getElementById('box2'),
        blah = `${val}px`;
  
        box1.style.height = blah;
        box1.style.width = blah;
        box2.style.height = blah;
        box2.style.width = blah;
}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* default initial values */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;

  margin-top: 2rem;
}

span {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 20%;
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 30%;
}


figure, #box1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: wheat;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}

figure {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#box1 {
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#box1 span {
  margin-right: 20%;
}

#box1 span:first-child {
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 0;
}

figure:before, figure:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  
  background-color: blue;
  height: 20%;
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

figure:before {
  left: 30%;
}

figure:after {
  right: 30%;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin: 2rem 0 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
Slide to change size: 
<input type="range" 
       name="fu"
       min="0"
       max="500"
       onchange="hiUser(this.value)"
       oninput="hiUser(this.value)">
       
<label>Flex;</label>

<div id="box1">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>


<label>Pseudo;</label>
<div id="box2">

  <figure></figure>

</div>
```